# Error when requesting HTTPS from SQLCLR Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014, .net-4.5, sqlclr

I created a SQL CLR stored procedure that is triggered when an INSERT happens in the database. The stored procedure then uses HttpWebRequest to make an API JSON POST.

The problem is that API uses SSL so when the stored procedure is triggered, I get an error:

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Procedure OnInsert, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 0]
> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "OnInsert":
> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

I am using SQL Server 2014 with .NET Framework 4.5, database is set to:

```
ALTER DATABASE TestDatabase SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;
```

Assembly is also using .NET Framework 4.5, and the permission state for the assembly used is: `EXTERNAL_ACCESS`; I tried using `UNSAFE` but still get the same errors.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
public readonly static string _url = "https://localhost:44381/api/test";
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static void OnInsert()
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_url);
    request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    request.Method = "POST";
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        string json = "{ \"Test\" : \"12345\" }";
        streamWriter.Write(json);
        streamWriter.Flush();
    }

    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
    }
}
```

I tried adding:

```
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

But I still get the same error.

When I added:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => (true);
```

I get this error:

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Procedure OnInsert, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 0]
> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "OnInsert":
> System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

I tried making the same call via Postman and it was successful. What is bothering me is that I even made a Console Application (.NET Framework 4.5) with the same code as in the SQL CLR stored procedure and it was also successful.

Here is my console app:

```
    public readonly static string _url = "https://localhost:44381/api/test";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Create();
    }
    
    public static void Create()
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_url);
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        request.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "{ \"Test\" : \"12345\"}";
            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Exactly where did you try adding  the `ServicePointManager` code?

Comment: Before HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_url); 
Why?

Comment: Is [the assembly signed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887783/securityexception-error-when-calling-clr-function)?

Comment: Nope, that's why I am using `ALTER DATABASE TestDatabase SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;` I wanted to make sure everything is functioning and sign the assembly later since I can set permissions to EXTERNAL_ACCESS and UNSAFE with TRUSTWORTHY on. You think that signing the assembly could solve the problem?

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure. Thinking back to when I once did this I think I signed the assembly.

Comment: I tried signing now by going to project properties -> SQLCLR -> Sign The Assemblly -> New -> Key file name: test.snk with password unchecked. Published the new assembly on the server but I still get the same error

Comment: OK so you are trying to connect to an HTTP server inside a trigger, and you have no exception handling code. That is a pretty bad idea #1 don't block on a trigger, as you will hold the transaction open and prevent the client from finishing the query #2 you **must** catch exceptions in SQLCLR. But any case, use Service Broker or a SQL Server Agent job in Powershell for this, it is much better placed to handle this type of thing.

Comment: loki_tata: With `TRUSTWORTHY` enabled, signing the assembly shouldn't make a difference (it's just what you do so that you don't need to enable `TRUSTWORTHY`). Is your assembly still marked as `UNSAFE`? With the callback returning `true` and this marked as `UNSAFE` and the DB marked as `TRUSTWORTHY`, it should work. That said, as much as I am pro-SQLCLR, I have to agree with @Charlieface that this is best handled via Service Broker or something else that isn't directly tying a trigger to an HTTP call.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky I tried switching from EXTERNAL_ACCESS to UNSAFE and back, still getting the same error. Btw I read some of your answers and both Stairway to SQLCLR and SQLCLR vs. SQL Server 2017, Part 1: “CLR strict security” – The Problem. Props man

Comment: loki_tata: Thanks, I really appreciate hearing that, and hope you have found that info useful. It sounds like you covered all the bases, at least in terms of getting it working. Who owns the DB? The login that owns the DB needs to have the `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY` permission, and might possibly also need to have `AUTHENTICATE SERVER`, but can't remember off hand. This is why so many folks go with `sa` as the owner as doing that masks the specific requirements as `sa` has them all. If you created the DB, the owner is you by default, which is fine if you are in the `sysadmin` server role.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky the DB is local on my PC for development purposes, won't stay that way. I am using Windows authentication on it, any suggestions?

Comment: Doesn't matter where the instance is located or what type of authentication is being used. What matters when `TRUSTWORTHY` is enabled is: does the login that owns the DB where the assembly is located have the `EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY` or `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY` permission, depending on which level you are using for the assembly/assemblies? Try: `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[your_db] TO [sa];`

Comment: @SolomonRutzky I successfully altered authorizarion to `[sa]`. Still getting the same error,  I am not sure how to check or change login permission. But as I said, the assembly is `UNSAFE` and DB `TRUSTWORTHY` is enabled

Comment: Can you connect to any site, or not using SSL? For `SecurityProtocol` might want to add protocols rather than set to just one. Try something like: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | 12288;` where 12288 == Tls13, introduced in .NET Framework 4.8. Also, just to put this out there, my [SQL# (SQLsharp)](https://sqlsharp.com/?ref=so_66341147) library does have a TVF that does this: **INET_GetWebPages** (only catch is that it's only in the paid-for Full version, not in the Free version, but still)..